# In search condition

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL NOT IN constraint and NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/sql-not-in-constraint-and-null-values)

Why is following query not returning hello?

```
select 'hello' where 'a' not in ('b', null)
```

Comment: Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296146/sql-query-question-select-not-in

Answer (score 3):

Your query can be expanded to:

```
SELECT 'hello' WHERE 'a' <> 'b' AND 'a' <> NULL;
```

The first condition evaluates to true.

The second condition evaluates to neither true nor false because NULL is neither equal nor unequal to anything.  The full WHERE clause is then: "true AND neither true nor false".

Comment: I think you meant: the first condition evaluates to TRUE, but the second doesn't, so the AND becomes FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't have a null value.