# PHP SQL Check Referential Integrity for whole DB

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, referential-integrity, generic-foreign-key

I was wondering if there was an option to check the referntial integrity of my database without checking everything manually. I must mention that I'm completely new to SQL and have the task to check the referential integrity.

With the search I found this question:
[how to find records that violate referential integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921144/how-to-find-records-that-violate-referential-integrity)

which was already helpful, but I got quite a lot of tables and I was wondering if there was a faster way than writting hundreds of the querys in the format of the question I found.

Thanks for helping,
Yíu

EDIT:
I know that most databases check that automatically, but I'm a student and the task says 
"These scripts should illustrate updating and referential integrity of your database.
! Please point explicitly where you check referential integrity (adding rows, modifying rows, deleting rows). "

So I guess I have to check it manually.

Comment: Those checks are done by MySQL automatically when you try to insert data (+ when you do not have disabled checks manually, + when you added referential integrity to your structure before).

Answer (score 1):

The most databases check referencing, like MySQL too. So have a look at `FOREIGN KEY` and `REFERENCES` command

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Sample from MySQL page

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT, 
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Child automatically check and need parent row. If you delete parents, all child rows will deleted to (ON DELETE CASCADE).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I guess I have to do it manually for practice reasons (see edited question). Would be nice if you could have a second look on it.

Comment: With ALTER TABLE you can add table contrains.

Comment: @Yíu Never do it manually. It's not intended to be done by hand. It's not safe at all. What you need is the part: `FOREIGN KEY (...) REFERENCES (...) ON DELETE ...` or `ON UPDATE`... see the linked docs.